# Detecting object(image) in image, created form overlapping images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one main image, composited from other images overlapped with z-index. Lets say we have a bathroom, and i have separate images for the floor, for the walls, for the lights, etc. And I build the hole space with z-indexing all of the small parts/images.
I want to detect when my mouse pointer is over a different part of the image, and to alert its name. For example when i'm pointing the floor, script says -> It's the floor.
I try different approaches but no luck at all. There is always some big element that can not be hidden very well with z-index, and its transparent background crosses the other elements, as well as it takes their hover events.

```
    $("#floor").attr('title', 'This is the hover-over text for the floor');
      $("#floor").on('hover', function () {
        console.log('this is the floor!');

   });
```

That's what i use for now -> floor is the id of my DIV IMG element holding the floor image.
This don't works well, because of edges of objects in images, and really i can't cut the images that good or i have triangles and rectangles which goes into another objects/image.
I try something with using canvas, but again i don't like the result, because canvas is wrapping everything in one big window, and can't manipulate each part of the image.
Can some one give me an advice what can i try, or what to use to do this.
See picture:

[image]

green is working fine, i get the right hover text, but red is wrong, because it tells me that i'm on WC, and i'm not.. i'm outside of the object and i'm on the floor.That's because it detects the transparent background of WC image.I want to find the exact size of each element. If this can help as example.

Comment: Hello. If you don't make a working example replicating your problem, we cannot help as much as you/we would like. So try and replicate your problem in a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can you Raphael Javascript Library for this: http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/

Comment: Thanks man, this library seems like will help me to make it.
I can draw a canvas for each of my elements in the picture and add events to them.

Comment: I'm happy it's useful for you. Can you accept my answer, please?